# Bootstrap Modal HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I am currently developing a website and I am having some issues with a modal.

So this is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Resultados</h2>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <h4>A tua média final de secundário é: </h4>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <h6>A tua média de acesso ao Ensino Superior é: </h6>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" style="background: #4a58ce; outline: none;">Ok</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="clicktoshow">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>
```

JS:

```
  var buttonc = document.querySelector("#clicktoshow");
  buttonc.addEventListener("click", triggermodal);

  $(document).ready(function triggermodal() {
    $("#exampleModal").modal();
  });
```

Right now when I use javascript to trigger this modal after clicking the button nothing happens.
I have tried multiple solutions and still can't figure it out.

**Note:** I am bit new to web developing

Comment: "_when I use javascript to trigger this modal_" Where is that code?

Comment: please post your javascript code

Comment: I just posted the code

Comment: You are using jquery to trigger the modal when the page is loading. That would be works correctly. However, if its not working means, you may forgot to include jquery dependency script links. Please check that once

Answer (score -1):

You can open the modal by adding a click event listener using jQuery. Once the button `#clicktoshow` is clicked, the `#exampleModal` will be shown. The code is-

```
$('#clicktoshow').on('click', function(){     
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show') 
})
```

Comment: I tried that but is does not work

Comment: @code_dev Have you included jquery dependency in the HTML file?